# Processing: display goes bezerk at about 1600 frames

Tags: draw, processing

I have an "art" application written in Processing that goes bezerk at about 1600 frames.  The code is at https://github.com/jxxcarlson/Processing/tree/master/seurat .  Try this to duplicate the error: (1) Start the app.  (2) Hit the space bar to bring up the controls.  (3) Wait until about 1600 frames.  Suddenly the controls will disappaear to 
be replaced by a large colored rectangle.  Ugh!  I've looked at the code from may angles, but must be missing something.  If one disables the body of the if statement in displayControls(),  in the "Seurat" tab, the error goes away -- but so do my controls. Yech!

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue starts when the `IF` below equates to true.

```
//Frames.pde
           if (frameCount > phase) {
              for(int i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
                particles[i].change(M);  // M = maximum particle radius
                particles[i].display();
              }
            }
```

Test this by changing `frames[i].phase = 200*i;` in `Seurat.pde` to `frames[i].phase = 10*i;`

I'll be honest, I haven't taken the time to read your code to know why, but now you can focus your efforts on that condition.

Comment: Thankyou very much!!  It was an obscure error that revealed itself only after some time.  (All due to bad coding on my part --- a mixture of rectModes that were not all set).  They need to be set within each display() method.